# How to capture ctrl+S and ctrl+Q in C

Tags: c, linux, signals

I am trying to change the default behaviour of the terminal when I press ctrl+S (freeze) and ctrl+Q (unfreeze). My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>


void sig_handler(int signum){

   printf("\nInside handler function\n");
}

 int main(){

 signal(SIGSTOP, sig_handler);

 for(int i=1;;i++){    
    printf("%d : Inside main function\n",i);
    sleep(1);  
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Before I run the code I disable the default behaviour by giving this command: stty -ixon -ixoff.

The problem is that when I run the code and press ctrl+S nothing happens, the characters ^S just get printed on the screen. Can I have some guidance oh how to do this or what to look for more information? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried reading input?

Comment: Also note that `printf` (or any `FILE*` function) is not safe to use from a signal handler, you have to output using `write`.

Comment: Or do you mean, how to have handler for SIGSTOP? I think that is not possible, it's like `SIGKILL`, process is just stopped (could be I'm wrong, verify).

Comment: ^S and ^Q don't send signals. You can make them send SIGINT or SIGQUIT or SIGTSTP, or you could read from the tty and take appropriate action when you see ^S or ^Q. If you can explain the underlying problem you're trying to solve, we might be able to suggest a specific approach to take.

Answer (score 0):

1 The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught or ignored
2 maybe using tcsetattr is a way for resolving your problem. modify characters for VSTART/VSTOP, then process ctrl+S by your program

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, improve your answer by better explaining what you mean and, if possible, add some example code.